# What template is used for viewing Media Library Files?

Tags: templates, page-template, media, child-theme, media-library

I would like to create a special page template in my theme for viewing the media library files.

Currently, when I click a Media Library image file I get a page template from the parent theme.

Does anyone know what template that is so I can tweak it as a child template?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create attachment.php in your child theme. Please [check here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Image_and_File_Attachments#Usage_in_Themes) for more details.